# Can't use jQuery ($.Storage.get) in a Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

When I type in the Chrome console `$.Storage.get('ui_s')` it returns value `"th_classic"` from a certain website as it should.
But when I try to use it in my Chrome extension it returns an error with following text: 
`TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`
What do I do wrong? All other jQuery functions I use in my extension work just fine.
*I couldn't find an answer because all search engines ignore "$." in my seach requests.*

Comment: Are you including the plugin for it? Why not just use `localStorage`?

Comment: The chrome extension i.e. background script runs in an isolated environment, it does NOT have access to the page. What you need is a content script.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know that `$.Storage` is equal to `localStorage` (but doesn't work for some reason). `localStorage` works fine. Thank you for the comments.